# Backbone: get data of item that was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js, click

I have a simple page where I display a list of books and a few details about the book, title, price, description. Data is pulled from a JSON file.

When I click on any of the books listed, a lightbox (bootstrap modal) fires up where I'd like to show the title of the book that was clicked.
User will be able to write a comment so I'd also like to get then send the book ID.

Not sure what is the best way to get the data from the book that was clicked?

Here is my code so far (including lightbox):

**Backbone:**

```
var Book = Backbone.Model.extend();

    var BookList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Book,
        url: 'json/books.json'
    });

    var BookView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '.booksList',
        template: _.template($('#booksTemplate').html()),
        render: function(){
            _.each(this.model.models, function(model){
                this.$el.append(this.template({
                    data: model.toJSON()
                }));
            }, this);
            return this;
        }
    });

    var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: 'body',
        initialize: function(){
            var bookList = new BookList();
            var bookView = new BookView({
                model: bookList
            });
            bookList.bind('reset', function(){
                bookView.render();
            });
            bookList.fetch();
        }
    });

    var appView = new AppView();
```

**Template:**

```
<script id="booksTemplate" type="text/template">
    <div class="book">
        <div class="bookDetails">
            <h3><%= data.title %></h3>
            <p><%= data.price %></p>
        </div>
        <p><%= data.description %></p>
        <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">bid</a>
    </div>

    <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h3><%= data.title %></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">    
            <form action="#" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="comment" id="comment"  />
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</a>   
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Does the `model` contain the book id?

Comment: Yes, book id is inside JSON file.

Answer (score 2):

Listen to the events in your view. [Source.](http://backbonejs.org/#View-extend)

So basically you'll have something like this in your view:

```
var BookView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.booksList',
    template: _.template($('#booksTemplate').html()),
    render: function(){
        _.each(this.model.models, function(model){
            this.$el.append(this.template({
                data: model.toJSON()
            }));
        }, this);
        return this;
    },
    events: {
      'click': 'openModal'
      // you could also use 'click selector', see the doc
    },
    openModal: function() {
      // here the context is your view
      // so this.model will give you your collection, hence access to your data
    }
});
```

However, I personally think that you should have several views, each for one model (=book), instead of a whole view for the collection. But hey, that's just an opinion.

**Edit: details**
I personally never create views for a collection. I prefer wrapping collections in another model (eg, as you have a list of books, a bookshelf...). But that's just if you need a unique element on top of the list of views.

To illustrate, say you ordered your books by genre. You'd want a wrapping view to display a title (to tell the user the genre). So you could use a wrapping model for your collection.
Now you simply want to display all of your books as one. You could only add as many views as you have books, inside some div or ul element. Hence you'd not need to wrap your collection.

I could go on forever about where, when and how I'm creating my views but that's not the point, nor am I qualified to do so (haven't had any computer science education, so you may question everything I'm saying, I won't resent you). So basically, you could just change your code to:

```
initialize: function(){
  var bookList = new BookList; // I'm removing the parenthesis here
  // I simply like to separate "new Booklist" which makes a new object
  // from "Booklist()" which just calls the function
  bookList.each(function(book) {
    new BookView({model: book});
    // here you may not need "book" and use "this" instead, not sure though
  });
```

Then there's the question of the binding. Again, I'll let you search for your solution, but it could be as easy as doing the binding inside the views' initialize function. There are a lot of possibilities.

Comment: Yep listening to events is fine. What I'm trying to figure out is how to get data from the book that was clicked then render it in my lightbox.

Comment: I thought so, that's kinda why I specified that you'd better have a view per book. Another way would be to use the "event" object passed to your listener and see what the user clicked on but... better make a solid MVVM.

Comment: I see what you mean, a view per book sounds like a better option. Can I ask you how you'd create a view per book?

Comment: @Patrice see my edit. I'll be more thorough if you ask, but maybe better thinking about it by yourself to find your own logical way :)

Comment: thanks for the tip. I updated my code and now have a view per book and now can get the data from the appropriate data on a book that was clicked. For instance by doing putting in the click event: console.log(this.model.get('title'));

Comment: One thing that's not totally clear. Now how can I pass the title to my lightbox/template (lightbox is part of the template)?

Comment: If your title is an attribute of your book model, the toJSON method should give you what you expect. What's the problem?

Comment: Correct title is an attribute here. For some reason it will only show title of the first object of my JSON (whichever book I'll click on).

Comment: Sorry but I'm not a magician, I'll need more elements if you want help on the subject. Could you upload somewhere (like pastebin) the content of your json file?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Sure, my JSON file is pretty basic, here is an example with 2 books http://pastebin.com/cvB72aqW

Comment: Well it seems I missed something in your comment. If only the title of the first book is shown whatever the book you click on, you surely gave the same model to all your views. Could you also paste your updated code?

Comment: Hey sure, is there a way I could send it to you privately? If not I'll try pastebin. (au fait t'es francais?)

Comment: Just sent you message from a room. Not sure if you received.

Comment: Seems like I didn't. Well anyway I'm off to sleep, I'll be available tomorrow.

Comment: No worries. Let's try the chat tomorrow. Thanks for your time.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27920/discussion-between-loamhoof-and-patrice)

Comment: Great, in the chat right now. Let me know if you receive my messages.